# overflow button in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can anyone explain why newer devices such as. Google Nexus 5 shows overflow button in the ActionBar even though it have the hardware menu button and the menu options are defined as "never"?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuOff"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_exit"/>
</menu>
```

Before I forget, I use **AppCompact7** and overflow button does not appear on other devices such as. Samsung S3/S4 with the same settings.

Comment: this should be a xml issue, use `youapp:showAsAction` instead of `android:showAsAction`, The overflow button AFAIK, is not shown in S2/S3/S4... as there is already a menu button which makes it redundant. So I believe sammy has tweaked the framework to their requirement. If it is not working correctly on a Nexus, It is not working as *it's intended*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:showAsAction="never"` means that the item will not be shown as an icon on the ActionBar, it will nevertheless be placed inside the overflow menu (or the normal menu if the device has a hardware menu button).

Comment: And is there any way how to force not to show overflow menu ? :)

Comment: None that I know of. I mean, it's also nice for the people to always have the menu at the same place, so I personally like it, that the overflow menu is enforced for devices without menu button.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an app with AppCompat library, you should use`app:showAsAction` instead:

So the menu would look like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        app:showAsAction ="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuOff"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_exit"/>
</menu>
```

this is a typical issue that is overlooked while using AppCompat, this should be listed in the lint error (I cannot vouch for Eclipse, but AndroidStudio lint shows this)

Answer (score 1):

Android is evolving os. In older version's android had 4 hardware keys(partly) Menu, Search, home and back. Then google decided to drop the search key. In api level 14 I guess the menu key was deemed unnecessary and the multiple selection(has same keycode as menu) key was added. Nexus 5 doesnot have a menu key. It adds a 3 dots either top or bottom of layout giving similar functionality as menu key and accessible in similar fashion as older menu related xml and java classes.